# Pass innerText to Angularjs Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to get the inner text of a `<p>` element in my Angular application and pass it to a method and a view using `ng-route`. So when a user clicks on the `<p>` element, the innerText is passed through a method, gets some data back, then returns a new view with the response data returned

```
<p ng-click="searchUser()">Bob Ross</p>
```

js

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute'])
  .config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider){
  .when('/searchUser:name', { 
        templateUrl: 'user-results.html',
        controller:  'searchController'
    })

app.controller('searchController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
    $scope.name = $routeParams.name;
    $scope.searchUser = function(){
        // do some stuff;
    }
});
```

I'm not sure how to grab the inner text of the `<p>` tag properly and pass it through the method (I'm likely way off); should I be binding it to my model and then passing as a routeparam?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What is this p tag supposed to represent? Is it supposed to be a search box?

Comment: It is an html paragraph element

Comment: Yes, but how does that text "Bob Ross" appear there?

Comment: It's the result of an AJAX get request. just a list of <p> tags

Comment: why would your ajax request be sending a list of `<p>` tags instead of just sending the data as JSON?  are you using some other library other than angular to populate this list?  one of the major benefits of angular is that you don't have to manipulate raw HTML in this manner, so searching for `<p>` tags like this doesn't seem like an efficient use of angular features.

Comment: I'm not sending a list of p tags, I just want to grab the text of the tag onclick and pass it through my request

Comment: That is exactly what I was wondering. I hope he is giving us the compiled result in the example above. If you had access to the JSON data from an API call, you can use the ng-repeat directive along with interpolation to to populate the p tags or better yet li tags.

Comment: you said that "It's the result of an AJAX request" when asked where "Bob Ross" came from.  is that not how it got from the AJAX request onto the DOM?

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming you're using `$http` to get the list of users in your controller, in which case you could do this:

```
<p ng-repeat="user in users" ng-click="searchUser(user.name)">{{user.name}}</p>
```

And in your controller:

```
$scope.searchUser = function(userName){
   // do some stuff with userName;
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in the $event argument to the searchUser function. You can then use the $event.currentTarget to grab the element. For more details on the $event object, [click here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression#-event-).

```
<p ng-click="searchUser($event)">Bob Ross</p>

$scope.searchUser = function($event){
    var username = $event.currentTarget.innerHTML;
}
```